# select resultset of counts by array param in postgres

Tags: arrays, postgresql, parameters, count

I've been searching for this and it seems like it should be something simple, but apparently not so much. I want to return a resultSet within PostgreSQL 9.4.x using an array parameter so:

```
| id | count |
--------------
| 1  |   22  |
--------------
| 2  |   14  |
--------------
| 14 |   3   |
```

where I'm submitting a parameter of `{'1','2','14'}`.

Using something (clearly not) like:

```
SELECT id, count(a.*) 
FROM tablename a
WHERE a.id::int IN array('{1,2,14}'::int);
```

I want to test it first of course, and then write it as a storedProc (function) to make this simple.

Answer (score 0):

Forget it, here is the answer:

```
SELECT a.id,
       COUNT(a.id)
FROM tableName a
WHERE a.id IN
    (SELECT b.id 
     FROM tableName b
     WHERE b.id = ANY('{1,2,14}'::int[])
    )
GROUP BY a.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify to:

```
SELECT id, count(*) AS ct
FROM   tbl
WHERE  id = ANY('{1,2,14}'::int[])
GROUP  BY 1;
```

More:

- [Check if value exists in Postgres array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231544/check-if-value-exists-in-postgres-array/11231965#11231965)

To include IDs from the input array that are not found I suggest `unnest()` followed by a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT id, count(t.id) AS ct
FROM   unnest('{1,2,14}'::int[]) id
LEFT   JOIN tbl t USING (id)
GROUP  BY 1;
```

Related:

- [Preserve all elements of an array while (left) joining to a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242182/preserve-all-elements-of-an-array-while-left-joining-to-a-table/11251259#11251259)

If there can be NULL values in the array parameter *as well as* in the `id` column (which would be an odd design), you'd need (slower!) NULL-safe comparison:

```
SELECT id, count(t.id) AS ct
FROM   unnest('{1,2,14}'::int[]) id
LEFT   JOIN tbl t ON t.id IS NOT DISTINCT FROM id.id
GROUP  BY 1;
```

Comment: thnx but it seems I'm having an odd array post from ``$.ajax();``

Comment: interesting, i want it to return 0 (zero) for any id's that are in the array which aren't found in the table... any idea's on that?

Comment: hmmm. so it seems that adding the array to the node-postgres query as ``select * from storedProc_func(Array[1,2,14]::int[]);`` only returns whichever return a result but what I really want is to return a result for everything, even if it's null or zero, such as ``select * from storedProc_func('{"1","2","14"}');``

Comment: @JamesVanLeuven: Consider the added solutions.

Comment: so yup - that worked... interesting that there is a left join of itself... can you explain to me why self joining (more or less) is the method which worked for this?   I have to admit it's a bit perplexing...

Comment: so how do i add other filter criteria?  say another integer for 

``
SELECT id, count(t.id) AS ct
FROM   unnest('{1,2,14}'::int[]) id
LEFT   JOIN tbl t ON t.id IS NOT DISTINCT FROM id.id 
WHERE location::int = '1'::int
GROUP  BY 1;
``

Comment: @JamesVanLeuven: There are simple solutions, depending on what you need exactly. Start a new question for a new question. Include the table definition, sample data, the desired result and clearly defined requirements. Comments are not the place. You can always link to this one for context.

Comment: Ok I've run your examples a few times and I notice that both versions omit the ```id``` if there is a null value within the count result - I still need to return that id number whether there is a count of 0 or null or an actual value.